# Getting warning "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*. Why am I getting the warnings?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am a beginner in C++. I am working on inheritance. I have written a code and compiled it and it seems to be working fine and I am getting the expected output. But when I compile it, I get 13 similar warnings. I am not sure what is the problem? How can I override these warnings? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
class Identity
{
protected:
    char *name;
    int dob;
    char* blood_group;

    Identity(char *iname="", int nlength=1, int idob=0, char *iblood_group="", int blength=2):dob(idob)
    {
        name = new char[nlength+1];
        strncpy(name,iname,nlength);
        name[nlength]='\0';

        blood_group = new char[blength+1];
        strncpy(blood_group,iblood_group,blength);
        blood_group[blength]='\0';
    }

    ~Identity()
    {
        delete[] name;
        delete[] blood_group;
    }
};

class Physical
{
protected:
    double height;
    double weight;

    Physical(double pheight = 0.0, double pweight = 0.0):height(pheight),weight(pweight)
    {
    }
};

class Registration
{
protected:
    int policy_number;
    char* contact_address;

    Registration(int p_num=0, char* addr="", int alength=1):policy_number(p_num)
    {
        contact_address = new char[alength+1];
        strncpy(contact_address,addr,alength);
        contact_address[alength] = '\0';
    }

    ~Registration()
    {
        delete[] contact_address;
    }
};

class Contact:public Identity, public Physical, public Registration
{
private:
    char* ph_number;
    char* driver_license;
public:
    Contact(char *name ="",int nlength=0,int dob = 0, char* blood = "", int blength = 0,double height = 0, double weight = 0, int pol_num = 0, char* cont_addr="", int alength=10, char *ph="",int plength=10,char* lic="",int llength=10):Identity(name,nlength,dob,blood,blength),Physical(height,weight), Registration(pol_num,cont_addr,alength), ph_number(ph),driver_license(lic)
    {
        ph_number = new char[plength+1];
        strncpy(ph_number,ph,plength);
        ph_number[plength] = '\0';

        driver_license = new char[llength+1];
        strncpy(driver_license,lic,llength);
        driver_license[llength] = '\0';
    }

    ~Contact()
    {
        delete[] ph_number;
        delete[] driver_license;
    }

    char* GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int GetDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    char* GetBloodGroup()
    {
        return blood_group;
    }

    double GetHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    double GetWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    int GetPolicyNum()
    {
        return policy_number;
    }

    char* GetAddress()
    {
        return contact_address;
    }

    char* GetPhoneNumber()
    {
        return ph_number;
    }

    char* GetDriverLicense()
    {
        return driver_license;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    Contact kck("MyName",strlen("MyName"),11111111,"A+",strlen("A+"),15.10,651.5,1111,"MyArea",strlen("MyArea"),"1111111111", strlen("1111111111"),"ABCD1234",strlen("ABCD1234"));

    cout << kck.GetName() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetDob() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetBloodGroup() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetHeight() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetWeight() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetPolicyNum() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetAddress() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetPhoneNumber() << endl;
    cout << kck.GetDriverLicense() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `strncpy`. It doesn't do what you think it does. Read its documentation carefully and think about the result when the string being copied is longer than the available space.

Answer (score 0):

In many places you write things like:

```
char *name = ""
```

However, `""` has type `const char[1]` . This implicitly converts to `const char *`.  But then you try to assign it to a `char *`,  which is an attempt to ignore the `const` qualifier.

Since C++11 this is not allowed at all. Before C++11 this was allowed but deprecated. The compiler is warning you that it's a bad idea.

If you really must use pointers, then use `char const *` for any situation where you might be pointing to a string literal.

But you would be far better off avoiding the use of pointers entirely, as they complicate your code and introduce the opportunity for errors where there would be none if you hadn't used pointers.  Passing the length of your strings separately from the string is extremely bad.

For example, use `string` to hold all of your strings. As a beginner, it would be good to begin with the easiest technique, which coincidentally is also the best technique.  The way you have written your program so far is just making life difficult for yourself for no reason.